# How to compute dBFS?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, sound, dbfs

I asked myself how to compute dBFS (dB full scale) from a value of sample between 1 and -1?

and in general?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is really quite simple for values between 1 and -1:

```
valueDBFS = 20*log10(abs(value))
```

If you have values between another range, for example 16bit, then it's:

```
valueDBFS = 20*log10(abs(value)/32768)
```

(because 16bit signed has values between -32768 and +32767, e.g. 2^15=32768)

And so the general formula is:

```
valueDBFS = 20*log10(abs(value)/maxValue)
```

The code examples are given in MATLAB code.

Comment: This is technically correct, but most dBFS meters actually display headroom, so you will often want to display the negative of these values.

Comment: According to the wikipedia article on [full-scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_scale), when using integers the positive value of the range is used for the max (i.e. 32767) and the maximum negative value (-32768) actually exceeds full-scale, which would mean the formula here should be `20*log10(abs(value)/32767)`

Answer (score 10):

[All the standards define dBFS as an RMS measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBFS#RMS_levels), relative to the RMS level of a full-scale sine wave, so the calculation is:

```
value_dBFS = 20*log10(rms(signal) * sqrt(2)) 
           = 20*log10(rms(signal)) + 3.0103
```

- A full-scale sine wave is 0 dBFS
- A full-scale square wave is +3 dBFS

The similar unit dBov is defined in relation to power ratios (so it's also an RMS measurement), such that full-scale DC or square wave is 0 dBov, so that calculation is:

```
value_dBov = 20*log10(rms(signal))
```

- A full-scale sine wave is −3 dBov
- A full-scale square wave is 0 dBov

(This definition of dBFS is explicitly designed such that the dBFS value of a full-scale sine wave equals 0 (and in consequence, that of a full-scale square wave is +3 dBFS). Since the [RMS of the full-scale sine wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) is `1/sqrt(2)`, multiplying `rms(signal)` by `sqrt(2)` ensures that the formula evaluates to 0 for the full scale sine wave: `20*log10(rms(signal) * sqrt(2)) = 20*log10((1/sqrt(2)) * sqrt(2)) = 20*log10(1) = 0`.)

Answer (score 2):

Relative to the RMS level of a full-scale sine wave, so the calculation is:

```
value_dBFS = 20*log10(rms(signal) * sqrt(2)) = 20*log10(rms(signal)) + 3.0103
```

Need some clarity about - > `value_dBFS = 20*log10(rms(signal) * sqrt(2))`
why in sin wave multiplying by `sqrt(2)`.

Please share your valuable information.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the `sqrt(2)` in the definition of dBFS given by

```
value_dBFS = 20*log10(rms(signal) * sqrt(2)) = 20*log10(rms(signal)) + 3.0103
```

is that this definition is explicitly designed such that the dBFS value of a full-scale sine wave equals 0. Since the [RMS of the full-scale sine wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) is `1/sqrt(2)`, multiplying `rms(signal)` by `sqrt(2)` ensures that the formula evaluates to 0 when `signal` is a full-scale sine wave:

```
20*log10(rms(signal) * sqrt(2)) = 20*log10((1/sqrt(2)) * sqrt(2))
                                = 20*log10(1)
                                = 0
```

In the more general case where the signal is in the range `[-v, v]`, the corresponding full-scale sine wave would be the standard sine wave multiplied by `v`. The RMS of this sine wave is `v/sqrt(2)`, which implies the correction factor should be `sqrt(2)/v`:

```
value_dBFS = 20*log10(rms(signal) * sqrt(2) / v)
```